# Finding Letter Combinations

Tags: java

For a string such as -u--('-' indicates a blank space), i'm given a letter lets say "d". The goal is for me to find all the combinations in which the letter d can be substituted in for the "-". A little hard to explain but, this is what an intended output would look like:

du--

dud-

du-d

dudd

-ud-

-udd

-u-d

I can't seem to find a set way of finding the combinations because I need to be able to find combinations of various lengths such as:

-u-----, or ----u-

Thanks for any future help, if more clarification is needed I can try to explain a little better.

Comment: I've messed around with some stuff, but haven't figured out anything that has worked. My problem is on the approach that I would take to finding the combinations. For instance I was thinking about If I added a concrete "d" to the first slot: "du--", I could then add one "d" at a time to the remaining slots "dud-" and "du-d", then add a second concrete "d": "dud-", then add "d" to remaining empty slots until I took all the empties up: "dudd". When this happens I clear back to the empty string and add my concrete "d" to the second open slot, and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This is best done recursively.

- Base case: combinations of the empty string are `[]`.
- Recursive case 1: to get combinations of `u.....`, get all combinations of `.....`; then prefix each one with `"u"`.
- Recursive case 2: to get combinations of `-.....`, get all combinations of `.....`; then prefix each one with `"d"`, and prefix each one with `-`, and concatenate the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to your problem:

```
public String[] getCombinations( String inputString ) {
    int dashCount = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++ ) { // checks how many '-' you have in the String
        if( inputString.charAt(i) == '-' ) dashCount++;
    }
    int uPosition = inputString.indexOf('u');
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    for( int i = 1; i <= Math.pow(2,dashCount)-1; i++ ) {
        String temp = String.format("%"+dashCount+"s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0'); // this returns a dashCount-bit binary number like 0001, 0010, for a dashCount of 4
        temp = temp.replace( '0', '-' );
        temp = temp.replace( '1', 'd' );
        arr.add( temp.substring(0,uPosition) + "u" + temp.substring(uPosition, temp.length()) );
    }
    Object[] tempArr = arr.toArray();
    return Arrays.copyOf(tempArr, tempArr.length, String[].class);
}
```

Idea is, treat all '-' as bits in a binary number, so count all occurrences of '-'. For convenience, we say we have n bits in the binary number.
Numbers from 1 to (2^n)-1 in binary will yield all possible combinations of 1's and 0's for the string.
Swap all '0' with '-', and swap all '1' with 'd'.
Insert 'u' to its original position.
Boom.

EDIT: altered code so you don't need third-party libraries.

Comment: Only need StringUtils for the dash count right? If so I can write a quick for loop to find them, I don't have much experience with Libraries.

Comment: Code is still buggy, I'm currently editing it for ya. :)

Comment: Ok I think I know the gist of what your doing.  If I had a string like "--ua-a-" and I needed the combinations of adding "d". Would I apply the same idea but also keep up with the positions of the additional letters?

Comment: @RIME, yes, that should be the idea.

Comment: Ahhh that makes complete sense now. Thanks a lot man. I appreciate you taking the time to write and explain this!

Comment: Sure thing! Had fun doing it. :)

Comment: My rep is so low it wont let me. I'm going to be on this website a little bit more, when I hit 15 rep I will for sure mark it as one.